# Can I have different metadata of the ERC-1155 NFTs with the same token ID?

Tags: nft

Let's say I mint 1000 NFT copies of token ID 1 to 1000 people. Now I want those ID 1 NFTs to have different in one of metadata, ex: Level.

So when user see the NFTs on the marketplace, they will see the same image, metadata except the different one.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: no you can't. The uri method used on ERC-1155 contract only take as parameter the tokenId so you cannot specify a "sub-id" under each tokenId.

The goal of the ERC-1155 is to be able to create "semi-fungible" tokens so have both fungible and non-fungible tokens but if you create more than one token with the same id it becomes impossible to differentiate them and you will attribute the same metadata to all the token under this id. They are non fungible because they have metadata and a specific id, but they become fungible because each token with this same id are equal (have the same metadata).

EDIT: For those who would be in a similar situation, you might want to take a look at the new Dual Layer token EIP: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6960. It adds a new layer of specification that can resolve this problem but it's still in draft at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. So I have to find a different approach then.